# I can't understand that is "wouldn't it be more sensible to leave before the traffic gets bad?"

Tags: meaning

I found this example "Wouldn't it be more sensible to leave before the traffic gets bad?" in online dictionary, and It's hardly understand to me. 
So, please let me know what that means. and I'd like to get some good examples(with basic word) about 'wouldn't it be' or stuff like that.

Comment: It means that we should leave before there is a lot of traffic.  What words are you having a problem with?

Comment: *I think we **would** like you to give more details of what exactly you find difficult here*. Or to put it another way, *Wouldn't it be a good idea to give more details?*

Comment: I'd like to advise you to visit our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), but please make sure you take the [tour](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit their [Help Center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) before posting any question. Don't post the same question on English Language Learners.

Answer (score 2):

"Wouldn't" is a contraction of "Would not", so expanded out it would read "Would not it be more sensible...", but "Would not it be more sensible..." is ungrammatical, and so it's really a contraction of **"Would it not..."** rather than "Would not it...".

In other contexts the contraction is more simple, such as "He wouldn't eat his dinner.", which just means "He would not eat his dinner".)

When you say "Would it not be more sensible to do X?", you are saying *"I think it would be more sensible to do X, don't you agree?"*  You are inviting the other person to disagree with you, basically.

It's actually hard to know whether one should reply to this question with "yes" or "no", if one actually agrees with the speaker:  the temptation is to say "Yes" if you agree with them, but then that seems like you are saying "Yes, it would not be more sensible to do that".  In reality, you are saying "Yes, it *would* be more sensible", but it's hard to explain this from a logical point of view.

People would generally answer the question as if the speaker had asked "Would it be more sensible..." (without the not).  This means that "Would it be more sensible..." and "Would it not be more sensible..." actually mean the same thing, which appears to completely defy logic!

In practise, you would say "Would it be more sensible to ..." if you don't have a strong opinion, and want the other person's advice, and you say "Wouldn't it be more sensible to ..." if you have an opinion, and you're arguing your point or trying to persuade the other person.